# search the detail of an image by sending it to server using any api in android

Tags: android, google-image-search

I am developing an application which search the detail of an image by sending it to server using search API in android.
I have tried the google image search API but it has been blocked.
I need help, is there any other API which i can use to search the detail of image by sending it to server?

```
public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {

    String upLoadServerUri = "http://www.xxxxxxxxxxx.com";
    String fileName = sourceFileUri;
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;  
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 2 * 1024 * 1024; 
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 


   if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
     tv.setText("File Not Exist");
     return 0;
    }
        try { 
            // open a URL connection to the Servlet

            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
         URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
         conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
         conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
         conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
         conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
         conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
         conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
         conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
         conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
         conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 
         dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

         dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
         dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""+ fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
         dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

         bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); // create a buffer of  maximum size

         bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
         buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

         // read file and write it into form...
         bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

         while (bytesRead > 0) {
           dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
           bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
           bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
           bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);               
          }

         // send multipart form data necesssary after file data
         dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
         dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

         // Responses from the server (code and message)
         serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
         //String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

        // Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);
         if(serverResponseCode == 200){
             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      tv.setText("File Upload Completed.");
                   // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });                
         }    

         //close the streams
         fileInputStream.close();
         dos.flush();
         dos.close();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Any big company that makes these API will give access to developers for free for only a limited number of API requests and after that they'll charge you for it or restrict access unless you get some kind of a licensing deal with them (not for indie developers). Having said that, for a hobby project or something these might be sufficient.

For example, you can try out the WikiMedia API:

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page

Here's a good article about the various Api's available:

http://blog.programmableweb.com/2012/02/22/203-photo-apis-flickr-foursquare-and-yahoo-image-search/

Comment: Bing is a text base image search api.i want image to image search api

Comment: Answer updated. Please upvote and accept so it'll help others too. Thanks